# Django ForeignKey and associated values in initial model

Tags: django, database, database-design, django-models, django-admin

First off, sorry for this somewhat crappy title: I wasn't able to find a short and explicaive title for this one .

I'm currently trying to create an app where there will be players and **each will have an inventory.**

The inventory consists of a ManyToManyField of Items.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=67)
    flavor_text = models.TextField(_('Flavor text'))

class Inventory(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, verbose_name=_('Items'))
```

I'm trying to implement a system where a player can, for example, have **3** bananas, **1** screwdriver and **17** loafs in his inventory.
As I'm very lazy, I don't want to enter manually *3 "banana" items* in my inventory.

However, putting a quantity field in the Item model would be counter-productive, as I would need to create an Item named "3 bananas", **another** "2 bananas", again and **again**.

I also tought of creating *Alice's* Bananas, *Bob's* Bananas, and change the quantity, but still, that's creating too much banana items : especially if I need to add **more players**.

So, here is my question: How can I associate a value (here, a quantity) to a ForeignKey, but **inside the model declaring the ForeignKey?**

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You don't have a foreign key, you have a many-to-many - which is good, because it means you can use a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) which is meant for precisely this.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I needed, thanks! Now I understand why I wasn't finding what I needed: I just messed up my research terms ! If you add this as an answer, I'll definitely validate it .